Нужна ли запятая? (Обособление дополнений/определений?)
Нужна ли запятая перед словом "гад":
К счастью для обсуждаемого лица, его в подвале не оказалось — на работе гад заносчивый!
Или
К счастью для обсуждаемого лица, его в подвале не оказалось — на работе, гад заносчивый!

Лучше так:
К счастью для обсуждаемого лица, его в подвале не оказалось — на работе, гад заносчивый!
При обособлении это будет оценка: он, гад заносчивый, на работе.
Правильно бывает по-разному! Можно и так: Этот заносчивый гад на работе.   Но у этого варианта ПОРЯДОК СЛОВ вызывает сомнения.* Так что остановимся на первом)

Спасибо!
Тоже склоняюсь к варианту, что запятая нужна) Хотя поначалу решила, что нет))


Нужна ли запятая перед словом "гад"?

Не нужна. Правильно без запятой:
К счастью для обсуждаемого лица, его в подвале не оказалось — на работе гад заносчивый!
